# How to make Label(s) field on Issue case-insensitive

Tags: jira

We are working with JIRA 6.0.8 and i would like to know how i can make `Labels` on Issues case-insensitive (like the behavior of Components field)

I have a `Component(s)` namend "ClientManagement" and when i type the letter **"c"** or **"C"** in the field Components of an Issue the Drop-Down gets filtered and the component ClientManagement is preselected.

[image]

The `Label(s)` field works a little diffrent cause it is case-sensitive. So if i have a Label named "Exception" and start typing "e", the Drop-Down does get filtered, but "Exception" is not in the List and i only have the option to create a new Label named e.

**Label(s) field typed in "e"**
[image]

**Label(s) field typed in "E"**
[image]

As far as i know are Labels used for all projects in JIRA and we really want to avoid that multiple labels are greated that differ only in upper and lowercase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vote for [JRA-24907 labels should be case insensitive](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-24907) - it's currently got 92 votes